# Create a matrix of sample : issue with np.apply_along_axis additional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I stumbled into a little issue trying to create a Matrix of randomly selected sample amongst a population using numpy.

What I want to create is a matrix, each line representing a sample from my population, so that I can do operations on each sample at a time more efficiently.

I tried doing the following:

```
import numpy as np

l = ["L"] * 36 + ["T1"]*20 + [0]*43

pop = np.array(l)

ech = np.random.choice(a = pop, size=7, replace=False)  # This is what I want my sample to be

A = np.full((30,1),7)  # Here I want 30 samples in my matrix

np.apply_along_axis(arr=A, func1d=np.random.choice, axis=1, a = pop)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: choice() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

As the `np.random.choice` function takes several argument, I created the matrix A filed with sevens (because I want samples of 7 elements from pop) so that the size arguments comes from the value of each line of A, and the a argument is given at the end by `a=pop`.

I was wondering if anyone knew what the mistake was here, and how to fix it.

I used the used the `np.apply_along_axis` to create this matrix of samples because I would have done it in a similar way with the `apply` function in R, but maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't try to use `apply_along_axis` if it confuses you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does the same thing as `apply` in R, the only problem is that I don't know where to put the additional arguments of the function I'm trying to apply, if there's a faster way to generate the samples with another  numpy function I'd rather use this one, but I imagine `apply_along_axis` is the way to go

Comment: Forget about the R analogy and any similarity in name.

Comment: If `apply_along_axis` is not the way to go, which numpy function should I use to generate matrix of samples, and do operation on all of them at once in python?

Comment: You haven't read the documentation carefully enough.  Pay close attention to how `func1d` is called, `func1d(a, *args)`.  `a` is a 1d array extracted from the `args` array.  The error is objecting to extra `a=pop` parameter.  You need a function that takes that `size` value as first argument.  But if `size` is just a number `7`, not a 1d array, I don't see why you are trying to use this extra layer.  `apply...` is not a speed tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted use of `apply_along_axis` is confusing, but I think you are trying to this:

One sample set from `pop`:

```
In [110]: pop = list('abcdefgijklm')
In [111]: np.random.choice(pop, size=7, replace=False)
Out[111]: array(['g', 'm', 'f', 'l', 'c', 'i', 'k'], dtype='<U1')
```

cast as a function that takes `size` as argument:

```
In [112]: f = lambda s: np.random.choice(pop, size=s, replace=False)
```

Straightforward Python iteration, generating samples of differing sizes:

```
In [113]: [f(i) for i in [3,5,4]]
Out[113]: 
[array(['j', 'b', 'l'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['l', 'e', 'k', 'm', 'b'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['k', 'm', 'j', 'b'], dtype='<U1')]
```

But to make an array of samples, the `size` needs to be the same, so we can do:

```
In [114]: np.array([f(7) for _ in range(3)])
Out[114]: 
array([['a', 'f', 'm', 'd', 'e', 'l', 'j'],
       ['i', 'g', 'f', 'b', 'j', 'e', 'l'],
       ['j', 'm', 'k', 'i', 'l', 'a', 'b']], dtype='<U1')
```

But since you insist on using `apply_along_axis`, here's a way:

```
In [122]: A = np.full((5,1), 7)
In [123]: np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, A)
Out[123]: 
array([['c', 'm', 'a', 'f', 'i', 'd', 'k'],
       ['j', 'm', 'k', 'd', 'b', 'l', 'g'],
       ['b', 'f', 'i', 'm', 'c', 'l', 'k'],
       ['k', 'f', 'd', 'l', 'b', 'c', 'g'],
       ['l', 'f', 'j', 'k', 'g', 'a', 'd']], dtype='<U1')
```

It will pass `np.array([7])` to `f` 5 times, and collect the results in an array.  In timings this `apply` version is a bit slower than my `[113]` iteration.

To pass `pop` as a parameter we'd have to define an `func1d` like:

```
In [135]: f = lambda s, a: np.random.choice(a, s, replace=False)
In [136]: np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, A, a=pop)
Out[136]: 
array([['j', 'd', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'l', 'k'],
       ['d', 'c', 'e', 'j', 'm', 'k', 'i'],
       ['l', 'g', 'j', 'k', 'e', 'f', 'a'],
       ['a', 'l', 'e', 'm', 'b', 'c', 'j'],
       ['j', 'e', 'g', 'f', 'l', 'd', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```

`apply_along_axis` can be useful when `A` is 3d (or larger), and you want to apply a function to one axis, and iterate on the others.  It's easier to apply than:

```
 for i in range...:
     for j in range ...:
         res[i,j,:] = func1d(A[i,j,:])
```

but you construct a 2d array (n,1), just you can iterate on the first axis, passing the 2nd (size 1) axis to the function.  Iterating on a (n,) array is conceptually, and computationally, simpler.